# Filter emails CC'd to an alias unless main Gmail address in TO or CC

Tags: gmail-filters

I'm hoping for help with a Gmail filter please.  I have an email `alias`, let's say abc@abc.com.

I am trying to create a filter that applies to emails that have the `alias` in the `CC` field but don't  also have my `main` Gmail address in either the `TO` or `CC` fields.

Then I want the email to come to my inbox like normal.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to web-applications. Make sure you've made an effort to solve your problem. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)